# filepicker.io after adding s3 credentials all files 404

Tags: filepicker.io

After I added S3 credentials to filepicker all the files 404. What's up with that? I assume this is because filepicker is trying to get the files from s3 instead its original location without trying to move it?

How do I ensure that filepicker migrates the files.

Answer (score 0):

We have a fix coming out for this in the next two days, in the interim we have a script that can migrate the files into your S3 bucket if you need them moved.

Comment: Please let us know when that's fixed

Comment: Hi there, yes sorry this was added a few weeks ago